# I have Implement Bluetooth to my app and when i click on Bluetooth on or Off the side closs and it comes a error Message

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

[![Screenshot App][1]][1]

I have Implement Bluetooth to my app and when i click on Bluetooth on or Off the side closs and it comes a error Message.

In line 158 startActivityForResult is crossed out and I can't find a solution in google why that is and how I can change it.

in

Code Main_Bluetooth:

```
package com.example.feuerwerkzndanlage;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Main_Bluetooth extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = Main_Bluetooth.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final UUID BT_MODULE_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); // "random" unique identifier

    // #defines for identifying shared types between calling functions
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1; // used to identify adding bluetooth names
    public final static int MESSAGE_READ = 2; // used in bluetooth handler to identify message update
    private final static int CONNECTING_STATUS = 3; // used in bluetooth handler to identify message status

    // GUI Components
    private TextView mBluetoothStatus;
    private TextView mReadBuffer;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBTAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mBTArrayAdapter;

    private Handler mHandler; // Our main handler that will receive callback notifications
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread; // bluetooth background worker thread to send and receive data
    private BluetoothSocket mBTSocket = null; // bi-directional client-to-client data path

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_bluetooth);

        mBluetoothStatus = findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_status);
        mReadBuffer = findViewById(R.id.read_buffer);
        Button mScanBtn = findViewById(R.id.scan);
        Button mOffBtn = findViewById(R.id.btoff);
        Button mDiscoverBtn = findViewById(R.id.discover);
        Button mListPairedDevicesBtn = findViewById(R.id.paired_btn);
        CheckBox mLED1 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_led_1);

        mBTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        mBTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // get a handle on the bluetooth radio

        ListView mDevicesListView = findViewById(R.id.devices_list_view);
        mDevicesListView.setAdapter(mBTArrayAdapter); // assign model to view
        mDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Ask for location permission if not already allowed
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);

        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){
                    String readMessage;
                    readMessage = new String((byte[]) msg.obj, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    mReadBuffer.setText(readMessage);
                }

                if(msg.what == CONNECTING_STATUS){
                    if(msg.arg1 == 1)
                        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connected to Device: " + msg.obj);
                    else
                        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connection Failed");
                }
            }
        };

        if (mBTArrayAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            mBluetoothStatus.setText("Status: Bluetooth not found");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth device not found!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {

            mLED1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    if(mConnectedThread != null) //First check to make sure thread created
                        mConnectedThread.write("1");
                }
            });


            mScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    bluetoothOn();
                }
            });

            mOffBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    bluetoothOff();
                }
            });

            mListPairedDevicesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    listPairedDevices();
                }
            });

            mDiscoverBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    discover();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void bluetoothOn(){

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence erlauben_txt = "Bitte Erlauben!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(context, erlauben_txt, duration).show();
        }

        if (!mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth enabled");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth is already on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    // Enter here after user selects "yes" or "no" to enabling radio
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent Data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, Data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // The user picked a contact.
                // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.
                mBluetoothStatus.setText("Enabled");
            } else
                mBluetoothStatus.setText("Disabled");
        }
    }

    private void bluetoothOff(){

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence erlauben_txt = "Bitte Erlauben!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(context, erlauben_txt, duration).show();
        }

        mBTAdapter.disable(); // turn off
        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth disabled");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void discover(){

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence erlauben_txt = "Bitte Erlauben!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(context, erlauben_txt, duration).show();
        }

        // Check if the device is already discovering
        if(mBTAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            mBTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Discovery stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            if(mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                mBTArrayAdapter.clear(); // clear items
                mBTAdapter.startDiscovery();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovery started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                registerReceiver(blReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth not on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    final BroadcastReceiver blReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            CharSequence erlauben_txt = "Bitte Erlauben!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main_Bluetooth.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(context, erlauben_txt, duration).show();
            }

            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // add the name to the list
                mBTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                mBTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    final void listPairedDevices(){


        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence erlauben_txt = "Bitte Erlauben!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(context, erlauben_txt, duration).show();
        }

        mBTArrayAdapter.clear();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            // put it's one to the adapter
            for (BluetoothDevice device : mPairedDevices)
                mBTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Show Paired Devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth not on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(!mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bluetooth not on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connecting...");
            // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            final String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
            final String name = info.substring(0,info.length() - 17);

            // Spawn a new thread to avoid blocking the GUI one
            new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence erlauben_txt = "Bitte Erlauben!";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main_Bluetooth.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        Toast.makeText(context, erlauben_txt, duration).show();
                    }

                    boolean fail = false;

                    BluetoothDevice device = mBTAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

                    try {
                        mBTSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        fail = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
                    try {
                        mBTSocket.connect();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        try {
                            fail = true;
                            mBTSocket.close();
                            mHandler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, -1, -1)
                                    .sendToTarget();
                        } catch (IOException e2) {
                            //insert code to deal with this
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    if(!fail) {
                        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mBTSocket, mHandler);
                        mConnectedThread.start();

                        mHandler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, 1, -1, name)
                                .sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    };

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence erlauben_txt = "Bitte Erlauben!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(context, erlauben_txt, duration).show();
        }

        try {
            final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", UUID.class);
            return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, BT_MODULE_UUID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        }
        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BT_MODULE_UUID);
    }
}
```

Code ConnectedThread:

```
package com.example.feuerwerkzndanlage;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    private final Handler mHandler;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, Handler handler) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        mHandler = handler;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.available();
                if(bytes != 0) {
                    buffer = new byte[1024];
                    SystemClock.sleep(100); //pause and wait for rest of data. Adjust this depending on your sending speed.
                    bytes = mmInStream.available(); // how many bytes are ready to be read?
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, bytes); // record how many bytes we actually read
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(Main_Bluetooth.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget(); // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(String input) {
        byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Error:

````
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 25028
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity } from ProcessRecord{ec058e4 25028:com.example.myapplication/u0a446} (pid=25028, uid=10446) requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2425)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:2607)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1743)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5541)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:712)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5494)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:693)
        at com.example.feuerwerkzndanlage.Main_Bluetooth.bluetoothOn(Main_Bluetooth.java:158)
        at com.example.feuerwerkzndanlage.Main_Bluetooth.access$300(Main_Bluetooth.java:36)
        at com.example.feuerwerkzndanlage.Main_Bluetooth$3.onClick(Main_Bluetooth.java:119)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7753)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7730)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:861)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29136)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityTaskSupervisor.java:1115)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:1072)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:734)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1276)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1246)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMrcb.jpg
````

Comment: The error message mentions "requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT", does your app have that?

Comment: yes in AndroidManifest i write:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLUETOOTH_CONNECT is a run time permission. You have to explicitly request user the permission to connect. For testing purpose, I would suggest granting the permission manually via `Android Settings > Apps > {Your App} > Permissions.`

Best practice is to always check for permission before calling these Android APIs to avoid such crashes.